# Paginating SPARQL results

Tags: rdf, sparql

Suppose I have the following SPARQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?result ?label
WHERE {
  ?result a database:Column .
  ?result rdfs:label ?label .
}
ORDER BY (LCASE(?label))
```

What can I add to the query to limit the number of results to the first 10 given? Or preferably, the 10 results after the first *n×10* results? I'm trying to implement pagination for visualizing the results.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I'm trying to implement a system of paging for a table that visualizes the returned data.

You want to use **limit**, **order by**, and **offset**.  They're described pretty well in the standard:

> #### [15.4 OFFSET](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modOffset)
>
> OFFSET causes the solutions generated to start after the specified
>   number of solutions. An OFFSET of zero has no effect.
>
> Using LIMIT and OFFSET to select different subsets of the query
>   solutions will not be useful unless the order is made predictable by
>   using ORDER BY.

> #### [15.5 LIMIT](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modResultLimit)
>
> The LIMIT clause puts an upper bound on the number of solutions
>   returned. If the number of actual solutions, after OFFSET is applied,
>   is greater than the limit, then at most the limit number of solutions
>   will be returned.

In your case, your query would be something like this to show the fourth page of results when you are showing ten results per page:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?result ?label
WHERE {
  ?result a database:Column .
  ?result rdfs:label ?label .
}
ORDER BY (LCASE(?label))
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 30
```

Comment: Hi! Would you know of a way to paginate SPARQL without offsets? [This issue](https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/49) and other resources point out the inefficiency of offsets for large results.