# How to extract RDF literals via SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, rdf

Assume we have a data set we know nothing about but has a public SPARQL endpoint. I want to issue SPARQL query/queries that would return all literals values in this data set. How does this query look like?

The reason I need this is that I intend to use the same query over many data sets. So, I do not need to navigate each of them to know which vocabulary they use for literals.

Also, not sure if this is true, but sounds reasonable to me, I believe these endpoints have some sort of a security measure so that one does not execute long-running queries over them. Is there a way to return these literals using LIMIT N. So I get these literals N by N instead of all literals via one query?

Comment: Especially that you asked for a way to limit the resultset lets me assume that you haven't had a look at any SPARQL tutorial.

Comment: As a hint, have a look how the query for the most general/common triple pattern + add a FILTER that restricts the objects of the triple pattern to be a literal + use some LIMIT N.

Comment: Yes, I knew about LIMIT and OFFSET. I just didn't want to direct the answer somewhere given that I didn't know what the best answer is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assume we have a data set we know nothing about but has a public
>   SPARQL endpoint. I want to issue SPARQL query/queries that would
>   return all literals values in this data set. How does this query look
>   like?

You'd check whether something is a literal by using the **[isLiteral](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isLiteral)** function with **filter**.  Literals can only appear in the object position of a triple, so if you just get each triple and check whether the object is a literal or not, you'll get all the literals.  Since some literal may appear more than once, you should also use **distinct** to eliminate duplicate results.

```sql
select distinct ?literal { 
  ?s ?p ?literal 
  filter isLiteral(?literal)
}
```

As for retrieving these in chunks of *n* literals at a time, that's typically called pagination, and that's been discussed and answered in another question, [Paginating SPARQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27488403/1281433).